# Why isn't updated model's value, updated via service, changing in UI?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Below, summary and test are set via MyCtrl. I'm seeing "my test" display properly, but not "summary.name". I'm seeing that MySvc.get()'s callback executes as expected, but summary.name's updated value doesn't appear on the UI.

Any suggestions on why summary.name's updated value isn't appearing on the UI ?

app.js:

```
...
.state('tab.edit', {
    url: '/edit',
    views: {
        'tab-dash': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/MyTemplate.html',
            controller: 'MyCtrl'
        }
    }
})
...
```

MyTemplate.html:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Name</span>
    <textarea rows="8" placeholder="Nothing yet." ng-model="summary.name"></textarea>
</label>
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">TEST</span>
    <textarea rows="8" placeholder="Nothing yet." ng-model="test"></textarea>
</label>
```

controllers.js:

```
...
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, MySvc) {

  console.log("MyCtrl: entered");

  $scope.summary = MySvc.get(0);
  $scope.test = "my test";
...
```

MySvc.get(0) returns ( and I see this callback execute and change ret.name ):

```
return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {

    console.log("MySvc callback: response.data = %o", response.data);
    console.log("MySvc callback: response.data.name = " + response.data.name);

    ret = new MySvc(response.data);

    console.log("MySvc callback: ret.name = " + ret.name);

    return ret;
});
```

Comment: Can't say what the problem is from what you have provided but here are some pointers.

This returns a promise (from .then): `return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {`

You should return a promise from service and resolve (`.then`) it in the controller and set `$scope.summary` there.

You need to provide more of MySvc to get to the main problem in the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You treated the return value of `MySvc.get` as a synchronous (immediately available) value. What is received via the $http service is not available immediately, so you can't treat it as a simple return value.

What you'll really want to do is use it as a promise, which it (most likely) is:

```
MySvc.get(0)
.then(function(summary) {
    $scope.summary = summary;
});
```

And you'll probably want to read up on promises, [Chapters 1 to 3](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20&%20performance/ch1.md) of "You Don't Know JS - Async & Performance" are an excellent starting point.